# Preferred method to update 'records' using hashid, id or some form of the above?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

This is an overall general design question around data integrity. I have an app that takes in user data and stores it in a DB. It is then "processed" via SSIS (SQL Service Integration Services). From this point the results are returned to the user and each record now has a Parent HASHID and it's own ID associated to it.

At this stage the user can add additional details to these records (comments, status updates etc) via an HTML form.

My question is what is the 'standard' process for tracking such changes. Create a new table for 'comments', one for 'status updates' with hashid references to the original record? OR, Update the original records and append each update to the same record (messy in my eyes)?

In the long term the app could get more complex or simplified so having a good frame-work will definitely keep things manageable for major changes. Just looking to get some general guidance.

I'm happy to add more detail but want to keep it non-specific as my question is quite broad.

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you tag this with MySQL?

Comment: @JohnConde Because in between HTML->SSIS sits a MySQL DB, and we also use a SQL Server DB.

Comment: I would assume that you may want multiple comments for instance - in that case you want another table with the hashid as FK.